# Help identify element on circuit board

Tags: identification, components

I have such board. It's a brightness regulator for lamp sourced from 220v. I circled placement for this element. It looks like a simple resistor but I'm not sure.
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's probably a DB3 diac or similar one.

Comment: You probably right because on schema also includes TRIAC

Comment: Looks like a zener diode. If you google 'zener diode through hole' you will see its looks like it. But zeners have polarity, the component you show doesnt seem to mark its polarity.

Comment: Did you try to measure it with diode test on multimeter?

Comment: the component label is DB1, so it is not a resistor